# DatePicker event not always firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery DatePicker control on my form and I need an event to fire every time a new date is picked. I am using `onSelect`, which works in most cases. But if I manually type in a date and then use the TAB key to move to the next field, the event doesn't fire.

Here is example code:

HTML:

```
<input id="datePicker" type="text" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            alert('test');
        }
    });
});
```

And here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcK2z/). Try tabbing out of the date picker and you will see the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: interesting... use `on change` maybe?

Comment: @SamCreamer -- I tried binding onchange also. The problem is, onchange doesn't seem to close the calendar after tabbing out of it.

Comment: I see... I've never seen this problem. If I come across a solution I'll let you know. I'll also be curious to see the solution myself

Comment: Not really a flexible solution (I only needed a quick fix at the time). I encountered this a while ago and ended up adding `readonly` to my datepicker input. This'll force users to pick a date off the calendar rather than typing their own value, meaning that the onSelect function will essentially always trigger as they have no other option.

Comment: @icemanind maybe also check for on `blur` of your datepicker input? http://jsfiddle.net/RcK2z/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that onSelect is only triggered via a mouse click to the date picker.. The following is one option you can use to additionally trigger the event for the case you mention above.

```
var typing = false;

$(function() {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            typing = false;
            console.log('test1');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            if(typing){
                typing = false;
                console.log('test2');
            } 
        }
    });
    $('#datePicker').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which != 9)
            typing = true;
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcK2z/3/)

Another option I thought of, if you just want to avoid the case all together and you know that your users won't be selecting dates years away, you could stop users from typing in the field altogether with something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            alert('test');
        }
    });
    $('#datePicker').keydown(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @icemanind please mark this answer as accepted if it resolved or question or leave feadback.  Thanks